# Error Using Stargazer to Display Regression Results

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels, stargazer

I want to use Stargazer to nicely display the results of my regression. And so far it has always worked but now I am running into an error that I have never seen before and that I can not figure out.

```
result = sm.OLS(independet,sm.add_constant(dependent)).fit()

stargazer = Stargazer(result)
```

This code, which so far, has always worked gives the following error message:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stargazer\stargazer.py in __init__(self, models)
     36     def __init__(self, models):
     37         self.models = models
---> 38         self.num_models = len(models)
     39         self.reset_params()
     40         self.extract_data()

TypeError: object of type 'RegressionResultsWrapper' has no len()
```

Did anybody encounter this error before and knows a solution to this issue?

Many thanks!!

Comment: based on the traceback, the code expects a list (or similar) of models. Try `stargazer = Stargazer([result])` if you have only one result.

Comment: It works! 
Thank you very much. I did not think about such an easy fix. My bad